# Value modified with form_alter revert after check_cache

Tags: 7, forms

Using Drupal 7.x.  Not much experience with Drupal.

I have a core form in which I need to append some data to a field after it's been submitted by the site visitor.  I have found I can alter the submitted data with a form_alter function added to my own custom module.  It works fine as far as that, but after the "prepare", $check_cache reverts values.

Is there a way to make this work?

Is there a way to manipulate the "uncacheable keys" to include my item?

Is there a different way to massage submitted data other than hacking the code?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Submitted form values are stored in $form_state['values'], and can be modified in a custom validation function.

So in your custom module, implement hook_form_alter() and add a validation function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'id_of_form_to_alter') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_form_validate';
  }
}

/**
 * Custom form validation handler.
 */
function mymodule_custom_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

  // Append value to submitted field.
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['myfield'])) {
    $form_state['values']['myfield'] .= ' append this string';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [`form_set_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_value/7.x) used to change submitted form values during form validation.

Please use [`form_set_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_value/7.x) instead of using `$form_state['values']`

Always look for the best practice. Good luck!

Comment: Just to mention you should make sure there is '&' sign before &$form_state parameter! .. (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id). sometimes developers miss that.